# AJAX with .change() not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 2 drop down menus. One of them shows the provinces in the country, and when one of the provinces selected, the second one should show the districts of the selected province.

The code below works properly and the drop down shows the provinces:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://blabla.com/dev/provinces"
        }).then(function (data) {
            var data = JSON.parse(data)["response"];
            var dropdown = $("#province");

            data.forEach(function (province) {
                dropdown.append("<option value=" + province["p_name"] + ">" + province["p_name"] + "</option>")
            });
        })
    });
```

However other drop down does not show the districts of the selected province by using the code below:

```
$("#province").change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://blabla.com/districts?province=["+ $(this).val()+"]"
        }).then(function (data) {
            var data = JSON.parse(data)["response"];
            var dropdown = $("#district");

            data.forEach(function (district) {
                dropdown.append("<option value=" + district["d_name"] + ">" + district["d_name"] + "</option>")
            });
        })
    });
```

Second code give the following error on console:

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token A"

What is the problem with the second one?

Thanks.

EDIT: HTML of the drop down menus' are like these:

```
<label class="dropdown-label" for="province">Province</label>
<select id="province"></select>

<label class="dropdown-label" for="district">District</label>
<select id="district"></select>
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to parse the JSON data as jQuery will do that automatially. Try `data = data.response` instead and see what happens. Perhaps add `dataType: 'JSON'` as an option if it complains.

Comment: Just put in some breakpoints, or console logs, or alerts and see what values are not what you are expecting them to be... easy!

Comment: @Franky storing the value in an variable didn't work

Comment: change ` var data = JSON.parse(data)["response"];` TO ` var data = JSON.parse(data);` and first check the console for `console.log(data);`

Comment: @Franky Tried that. Console gives just the error I mentioned.

Comment: @polifonik: Unexpected token often means invalid JSON. Try without parsing `data`. Just use `data` as if it is already parsed (which is should be). Like Andy already suggested

Comment: @polifonik in your console see what are you receiving click on the link in console, check for the post data and returned result.

Comment: @musefan Tried data as suggested with alert, it gives "undefined" and also I got an error for forEach: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined"

Comment: When I delete "var data = JSON.parse(data)["response"];" I no longer get the error. But I need to parse data to get a specific variable in it, how can I do that?

Comment: make the first line `console.log(data);` and post the result the is output to your browser console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be the response coming from the RESTful API call, which was not JSON by accident. When I fixed it, the code I posted worked fine. Thanks anyways.